# How do I make netcat timeout nonsilently?

Tags: linux, freebsd, netcat

I'm trying to send some data to a server with a command like `nc -w 3 IP_ADDRESS PORT < data` where nc is the [netcat from FreeBSD 5.4](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=nc&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD%205.4-RELEASE). When the server doesn't respond within 3 seconds I get no indication of it at all (exit code is 0 and there is no terminal output). How can I send data to the server and be alerted when a timeout occurs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the verbose option and check the output count of bytes sent is non-zero.
For example, using awk to exit 1 if the count is zero:

```
nc -v -w 3 localhost 80 2>/tmp/log
awk '/bytes sent/{exit($2==0)}' < /tmp/log
echo $?
```